# elasticsearch - index size change

Tags: elasticsearch

I insert some data to elasticsearch and here is result screen from es-head.
I do nothing but size is getting smaller. why? and can it be bigger somehow?

[image]

Comment: Can share code snippets showing how are you inserting the data?

Comment: data inserting from spark application. can it be problem?

Comment: if you are deleting something before insertion, it can be possible that overall size will shrink, because elasticsearch delete operation doesn't free up space, there is another "purge" operation that spark might be launching to free up space. It would be helpful if you share code snippets

Comment: there is no delete operation. it has only insert operation.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch (or actually the underlying Apache Lucene) writes data immutably. The only way to decrease the file size is through a [merge](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-merge.html), which will happen automatically in the background.

Quoting from the documentation:

> Smaller segments are periodically merged into larger segments to keep the index size at bay and to expunge deletes.

I would only expect bigger changes if you have lots of deleted documents. Note however that every update is treated as a (soft) delete and insert — immutable nature of Lucene segments.